# PayPal: charge customer at server side using token created at client side

Tags: laravel-5, paypal, vuejs2

I need to create a payment (sending a call to some PayPal URL which I don't know) on client-side (vue) which will return a token on valid card details, and then execute the payment processing using this token on Laravel Server (Just the same way as stripe allows).

How can I achieve such a solution?

Comment: This is way too broad. What have you tried? What errors are you facing? Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service; you're expected to attempt to solve the issue yourself, and if you have any specific errors, then ask a question.

Comment: @sinanspd yes I have read the documentation and I can't seem to find the endpoint or url which returns me a token (in fact I just see complete client-side implementation and just server side) which I can use on my server side to process the payment. Kindly do tell if you know what to do.

Comment: you don't specifically ask for a token, you configure button to call your server, where you can authorize and execute the payment https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/server-integration/

Answer (score 0):

While too broad a question, there are a couple code demos that might help the asker better understand how to implement what they want to do:

[Client-side demo](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client)

[Server-side demo](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server)

So, instead of fetching a token via the server, as in the Server-side demo, the Client-side's method could be used to initiate the payment instead -- and a server v2/orders API call only used for the capture step.

---

I'm not sure *why* the asker doesn't want to fetch the token via their server to start (as in the full server-side demo), which would be more locked down and secure --- but well, per their requirement it's possible for the client JS to set up the payment, as in the beginning of the client-side demo, and then later capture via the server.